# mouse enter mouse leave help for a big array of info

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseenter, mouseleave

i would like too set a link for every state ,and every city.
 when the state li is hovered over i only want that this states cities to show ....
but i kno only a little jquery code and im not perfect with understanding the selectors,
im not to sure on how to use the .each jquery function.... please help!!!!
php code:

```
<?
$everything = array(
        'states'=>array(
            'Alabama'=>array('Birmingham,Montgomery,Mobile,Huntsville,Tuscaloosa'),
            'Alaska'=>array('Anchorage,Juneau,Fairbanks,Sitka,Ketchikan'),
            'Arizona'=>array('Phoenix,Tuscon,Mesa,Glendale,Scottsdale'),
            'Arkansas'=>array('Little Rock,Fort Smith,North Little Rock,Fayetteville,Jonesboro'),

        )
);
$id = md5(0);
$controll = 0;
$here = md5('states');
echo "<div id=\"9090\"><ol id=\"selectable\">";
    foreach($everything['states'] as $state=>$city){
    $citys = explode(',',$city[0]);
    echo    "<li class=\"ui-state-default\"><a class=\"contr\" href=\"#\">$state</a> <div class=\"citys\">";
        foreach($citys as $key=>$x){
            echo "<a href=\"#\">$x</a><br>";    
        }
    "</div></li>";
    }

echo "</ol></div>";
?>
```

jquery :

```
    <script>

        $(function() {
            $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
        });
        $('.ui-state-default').mouseenter(function(e) {
// here when i hover over this state all citys show i just want the cities for this sate
            $('.citys').toggle();
        }).mouseleave(function(e) {
// here when i leave  this state li all theese citites should leave
            $('.citys').toggle();
        });;

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add context when finding the cities, like this `$('.citys', this).toggle();`
This will search for `.citys` elements located inside `this` which in this case is the hovered `.ui-state-default` element.

```
        $('.ui-state-default').mouseenter(function(e) {
            $('.citys', this).toggle(); // added this 
        }).mouseleave(function(e) {
            $('.citys', this).toggle(); // added this 
        });
```

See how to use the context parameter at http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

---

Alternatively you can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find)

```
$(this).find('.citys').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. Look up "css: hover"... this can all be handled by the stylesheets.